# Why TBN matrix is not computed on the normal mapping texture?

Tags: opengl, shader

As I understand, TBN matrix is used for every triangle of a 3D shape. The calculation takes 3 vertices coordinates and 3 pairs of UV coordinates as an input and finds the transformation of the UV plane that matches 3 UV points to 3 vertices in the object local space.

Since all the input information is available in 3D software after UV unwrapping of a model, why this calculations are not done at the moment of creating a normal map image and not encoded in it right away?

Why it needs to be done at a shader level?

Comment: "Why it needs to be done at a shader level?" Who does this in the shader? You would either have to use a geomettry shader or go through some ugly hoops to even be _able_ to do this in the shader. It is typically either directly stored in the model file or calculated at load time. The only thing the shader does is interpolate the actual T,B,N vectors per fragment.

Comment: I'm reading, for example, this article http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial26/tutorial26.html
Are you saying that normal mapping image already has TBN transformed vectors in it?

Comment: And that example doesn't do _any_ of what you claim in the shader. It calculates T and B at load time and just transforms and interpolates them in the shader, as it should.

Comment: My main question is - why not calculate T & B at the moment of creating normal map image and put those in it right away?

Comment: Not sure what your question is then. That is what every real-world software does anyway, and the example just shows how to calculate it in the first place, if you do that at model creation or load time is totally irrelevant for what the tutorial is trying to show. But nothing of this is ever done in a shader at render time.

Comment: My question is - why TBN calculations are not already in the image/texture itself and they need to be calculated separately from the texture at the runtime.

Comment: Because the same texture is applied to different triangles that would have a different TBN. You can, theoretically, pre-bake your normal map with TBN applied to it if you fully unwrap your model, but it's not going to work if your model animates and deforms.

Comment: Basically what you're asking is a [model-space normal map](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/88353/why-are-normal-maps-predominantly-blue). They exist, but they have limited application.

Comment: @Yakov Galka - I see, I didn't know model-space maps also exist. That answers my question, thank you!